# AngularJS Directive isn't rendering template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My view is simple:

```
<job-template ng-if="job"></job-template>
```

My directive:

```
.directive('jobTemplate', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope,element, attrs) {
        var JobStatus = scope.job.JobStatus;
        var text = "<p>"; 

        if(JobStatus === 'Created'){
          text += "{{job.id}} was created."
        }

        else if(JobStatus === 'Processing'){
          text += "{{job.id}} is currently processing."
        }

        text += "</p>";
        console.log("text");
        console.log(text);
        return text;
    }
  };

})
```

When I run my page, my `<job-template>` element isn't replaced with anything - although the correct `text` is loaded to the console.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

`link` function isn't meant to used for returning a HTML as you are thinking, It is basically meant to be there, to provide control over angular compiled DOM, when scope is linked to directive element. You could have html over `template/templateUrl` option in directive. Use `ng-if` for having conditional element.

**Directive**

```
.directive('jobTemplate', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<p>'+
        '<span ng-if="job.JobStatus == \'Created\'">{{job.id}} was created.</span>'+
        '<span ng-if="job.JobStatus == \'Processing\'">{{job.id}} is currently processing.</span>'+
      '</p>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
  };

})
```

[**Demo here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/IHMpsVbBg2rOatRGZcvS?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code https://plnkr.co/edit/cpdAqWN0SeUx5Gy9CQkR?p=preview

```
app.directive('jobTemplate', function($compile){
  return {
restrict: 'AE',
replace: true,
link: function(scope,element, attrs) {
  console.log(element)
    var JobStatus = scope.job.JobStatus;
    var text = "<p>"; 

    if(JobStatus === 'Created'){
      text += "{{job.id}} was created."
    }

    else if(JobStatus === 'Processing'){
      text += "{{job.id}} is currently processing."
    }

    text += "</p>";
    element.html(text);
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
 }
};
})
```

Comment: the way you are implemented is correct..but you should left conditional adding or removing part of DOM should using `ng-if`, so that wouldn't make a problem if `job` value will loaded by an ajax.

Comment: We can do this too within directive. Previously i made with the wordpress SPA. It's too much long directive so not possible to mention those all things but i managed by using **scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function(){})** within directive.

Comment: $watch on `$viewContentLoaded` loaded wouldn't work too..you need to specifically place a watch over `job`, but that would be an bad practice to have `$watch` in code.. Try to avoid watchers so that code will be more cleaner..

Comment: Yup agree with you. Sometime different environment and technology don't allow than this. In my case wordpress is totally useless but client choose that only technology and he never left option for me.

Comment: that's why I said you are correct.but that will only work with static data as you mentioned..